# Updating record if checkbox is checked

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-update

I am creating a simple POS system but I ran into an error. On the checkout form, it displays an Invoice Id, a subform of the items I have in my [Cart] table, checkout button, and 3 check boxes: Sold no tax, Sold tax, and Internal use. What I want is if you select cboxSoldNoTax and click checkout, all the items in [Cart] would update to 'Yes' under the field "SoldNoTax." But the problem is when I click the checkout button , I would receive this error message:

*Run-time error '3464':*

*Data type mismatch in criteria expression.*

Below is my vba code:

```
Private Sub btnCheckout_Click()
    txtInvoice.Value = DMax("InvoiceID", "Invoice")

    If cboxSoldTax.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Cart] SET SoldTax = 'Yes' WHERE InvoiceID = '" & Me.txtInvoice & "'"
    End If

    If cboxInternal.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Cart] SET InternalUse = 'Yes' WHERE InvoiceID = '" & Me.txtInvoice & "'"
    End If

    If cboxSoldNoTax.Value = True Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Cart] SET SoldNoTax = 'Yes' WHERE InvoiceID = '" & Me.txtInvoice & "'"
    End If

End Sub
```

I also provide a link to the access database. Here is the instructions to using the database: "Start" form -> Main Menu -> Flask -> Select quantity -> Add to Cart -> Checkout button -> Select either of the 3 checkbox -> Checkout button.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bye-M8FI1tRUYm9QT3o5a0tyMkE/view?usp=sharing

Any help or suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the datatype of `InternalUse.InvoiceID` is numeric instead of text, eliminate the single quotes before and after `Me.txtInvoice`: `" ... WHERE InvoiceID = " & Me.txtInvoice`

Comment: If `SoldTax` is Yes/No field type, set the value to True instead of 'Yes': `SET SoldTax = True`

Comment: Thank! @HansUp That solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datatype of `InternalUse.InvoiceID` is numeric instead of text, eliminate the single quotes before and after `Me.txtInvoice`:

```vb
" ... WHERE InvoiceID = " & Me.txtInvoice
```